# How can I watch slowed down Youtube videos in iPad?

Tags: macos, ipad, video, ios, youtube

I found this tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ts6vF5fllQ) but I am unable to find such type of buttons in iPad. I am also unable to slow down videos in OS X. I am trying to watch this video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooKF4hxjaSM) but it is too fast educational video. So how can I watch slowed-down videos?

Comment: If you had Google Chrome Extensions, you could follow the instructions [here](http://superuser.com/questions/525013/how-to-download-youtube-videos-in-google-chrome-browser) but the extensions are not supported in iPad, more [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chrome/UkG8RMYWUKk). It looks like you need to find some application to watch slowed-down videos. I haven't yet found any such app.

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial on slowing down YouTube videos was made in iOS 5 with the older YouTube app. You probably have iOS 6 and are using the YouTube website or the YouTube app released by Google more recently.

Both the web app and the YouTube app no longer play videos with the QuickTime player with those controls. The only thing that still uses that interface is the YouTube app on the iPhone. I suppose you can try experimenting with other third-party YouTube video viewers, one of those may use QuickTime for playback, but I don't have experience with them.

By the way, I don't know how useful that video will be even slowed down, and there are a lot of great Blender tutorials out there if you look.

EDIT: Actually, embedded YouTube videos will use that player, so you just have to embed the video on a web page and then browse to that page on the iPad.

Comment: ...yes I am using iOS 6 so it explains the difference +1, odd that they removed this feature -- making it painful to watch this kind of videos.

Comment: Actually, as it turns out, if you embed the video on another web page (you could do it for free if you make a blog), it will play in the Quick Time player. And then to get slow motion, you have to press and hold the fast-forward button when it's not playing to get it slow motion (pressing it when it's playing speeds it up).

Answer (score -1):

I made an action extension for iOS Safari that does just that. For those unaware, action extension basically adds button to Safari action sheet that allows you to adjust video playback speed. Works on both iPhone and iPad. It works with YouTube and virtually any other HTML5 video player, in Safari itself, rather then having to open different app. https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1205188880